# Exception: UCAExc:::4.0.2 unexpected token: 2017 required: )

Tags: java, ms-access, ucanaccess

When I insert date to microsoft Access it gives me this error, why?
what it means? I am sure that the query is correct.
this is my code:

```
try {
                final DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
                Date date = new Date();
                String a = "#"+sdf.format(date)+"#";
                conn=DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
                System.out.println("Connection ok.");
                id = Integer.parseInt(ID.getText());
                String query = "INSERT INTO Patient(ID, FName, Address, Phone, Allergies)\n" + 
                        "VALUES ('"+id+"', '"+ name.getText()+"', '"+ address.getText()+"', '"+phone.getText()+"', '"+allergies.getText()+ "');";
                PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                stmt.executeUpdate();
                String query2 = "INSERT INTO Visit( PatientID, ArrivalTime, HeartRate, Temprature) "+
                        "VALUES ('"+id+"','"+a+"', '"+heart.getText()+"', '"+temp.getText()+"');";

                stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query2);
                stmt.executeUpdate();
                conn.close();

            }catch(Exception e){
                System.err.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
            }
```

Comment: please add the stacktrace

Comment: AFAIK, there shouldn't be single-quotation marks around a date literal - i.e. `+"','"+a+"', '"+` should just be `+"',"+a+", '"+`.  Single-quotation marks should only be placed around text fields, not numerics and dates.  (Which also means you may not want it around `id`, `heart` and `temp` either, but it depends on what your actual Access field data types are.)

Comment: @AhmadAl-Kurdi That's right, thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

With the statement

```java
String a = "#"+sdf.format(date)+"#";
```

you have already put `#` delimiters around the date string. Then your dynamic SQL proceeds to put `'` delimiters around that, resulting in something like

```sql
INSERT INTO Visit (PatientID, ArrivalTime, ...) VALUES ('1', '#12/29/2017 06:24:23 PM#', ...);
```

which is invalid syntax. The correct literal syntax would be ...

```sql
INSERT INTO Visit (PatientID, ArrivalTime, ...) VALUES (1, #12/29/2017 06:24:23 PM#, ...);
```

... but you really should **not** be using dynamic SQL. You should be using a parameterized query along the lines of

```java
// test data
int id = 123;
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();

String sql = "INSERT INTO Visit (PatientID, ArrivalTime) VALUES (?,?);";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setInt(1, id);
ps.setTimestamp(2, new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime()));
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Actually I didn't know about the parameterized query .